# How do you insert content to a custom status cel which contains a UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, custom-cell

I have two view controller that for adding my "Routines". One is to display a list of all routines and one to edit/create routines.

In the first view controller I have two way to enter to the second controller

1. by selecting an already created routine
2. by pressing the "+" button on the navigation bar

If the press option is pressed the data should be recalled from CoreData entity and the fields in the second view controller shall be populated.

But I get the error:
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Would anyone know how to insert content to a custom status cell named "NameCell" which contains a UITextField?

Thanks in advance,
Ace

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using static cells in your table view in the storyboard, but want to populate data in one of them, one does not implement any of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods, but rather just create `IBOutlet` from the `UILabel` in question, and then you can populate it as you see fit.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var foo: UILabel!
    var bar: String!  // this is populated by `prepareForSegue` of presenting view controller

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        foo.text = bar
    }

}
```

As the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW2) says:

> **Note:** If a table view in a storyboard is static, the custom subclass of `UITableViewController` that contains the table view should not implement the data source protocol. Instead, the table view controller should use its `viewDidLoad` method to populate the table view’s data. For more information, see [Populating a Static Table View With Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW31).

Comment: Ok great I'll try it out. I guess I confused myself because I wanted to make sure that's the variable "bar" is only used if you access the controller using the selection of the routine, otherwise the fields should stay empty or default value

Comment: Good luck. By the way, I notice that your attempt at `prepareForSegue` in the first view controller was trying to set some variable in the first view controller. But that's not available from the `viewDidLoad` of the destination controller. You generally have the first vc set a property in the destination controller (e.g., in `prepareForSegue` in the first, you'd do something like `if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? AddRoutineTableViewController { controller.foo = ...}`).

Comment: Ok I tried this             if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? AddRoutineTableViewController {
                controller.NameCellTextField.text = "test"} but it crashes saying fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I changed it to this controller.NameCellTextField?.text = "test", now it doesn't crash but the content isn't changed

Comment: @AceGreen No, you cannot set the text property of the `@IBOutlet`, because the view hasn't been loaded yet (the `NameCellTextField` is undoubtedly `nil`). You have to just set some string property, and then the `viewDidLoad` of the destination would grab that string property and use it to set the text field's `text` property.

Comment: Isn't that longer than making the a global variable and passing it to the second view controller and using it there? Also in my second VC, view did load method, would I need to check if the segue was used? because to there is two ways to get to my second VC

Comment: Global variables are frowned upon because it's too easy to have unintended consequences as the app gets larger, as the use and intent of the variable isn't controlled. So it may be an extra few line of code, but "just say no" to globals. Re second vc, no you don't need to check to see if segue was used: you have your property that it set and that's all you need.

Comment: Ahh understood :) so the reason we don't cheap for segue is because the property is only changed if the segue was selected. if we got to the second VC another way (i.e. using the "+") it wouldn't have that property, therefore it would be empty?